# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined after subscribe()

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

My code in app.component.ts

```
    editFood(foodId) {
    console.log('Edit');
    this.dataService.sendGetByIdRequest('/Foods/', foodId)
        .subscribe((data) => {
            let item = data;
            console.log(item);
            
            this.newFoodForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                id: [''],
                imgSrc: [''],
                title: [''],
                desc: ['']
            })
            this.newFoodForm.setValue(data.result);
        })
    }
```

My HTML in app.component.html

```
        <div class="scroll-x-container" id="ctnPopularFood">
           <div *ngFor="let food of products">
                <div class="card mr-2" id="div_card{{food.id}}">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src={{food.imgSrc}} alt="{{food.title}}"/>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-title">{{food.title}}</p>
                        <p class="card-text">{{food.desc}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary (click)="editFood(food.id)">Edit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The edit getById can get this food but I can't bind data in form and allow me edit it at form.

It is my screenshot error here

[Picture Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PFjF.png)

Comment: In StackOverflow, if an error log can be suggested in text, it is guided to present it in text format. Not an image. See the documentation below. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) / [do-not-post-image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to improve your question (a lot) in order to make it easier for people to understand what you are asking and to help you.

As you can see from the exception, the problem is in line 334 of `app.component.ts`; however, you are not showing what is there! Since you are new, people will cut you some slack - once.

---

It is important to note that the code after `this.dataService.sendGetByIdRequest()` is executed *before* you get response from the service. So, assuming you have something like `this.newFoodForm.id` in line 334, `this.newFoodForm` is not yet assigned, and that's why you are getting this error. You have to handle the results *inside* `subscribe()` function